# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setup_logger' with non root user

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I have a module `setup_logger.py` with below contents:

```
import logging
import os

base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

logging.basicConfig(format='[%(asctime)s]:[%(levelname)s]:%(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',  filename=os.path.join(base_dir, 'dummy.log'), filemode='w',level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('spam')
```

I created this file using root user but I want to use it using a non root non sudo user so I changed the ownership for this module `setup_logger.py` and also the directory containing this module to the non root user `dummyUser`

Now when I am trying below import from `dummyUser` it is giving `ModuleNotFoundError`:

```
from setup_logger import logger
```

Also this module is present in root directory that is `/root/`

I am able to import this using root user.

Any clarification as to why this is happening will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is making the file a pip package.

First thing you have to do is put it in a folder called `setup_logger` wich is in a folder named src.

Then in the top folder you can make a file called `pyproject.toml` with the following contents :

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "setup_logger"
```

And after that, all you have to do is do the command `pip install -e .` in the top directory and you will be able to use `from setup_logger.setup_logger import logger` on every python project.

Just make sure to not use it if the code isn't going to be only on your computer